# Encrypting email using RSAES-OAEP & AES

Tags: java, encryption, x509certificate, bouncycastle, smime

I'm using Bouncycastle SMIME package to encrypt messages using rsassa-pss certificate:

```
openssl x509 -text -in certificate.crt | grep -i "algorithm"
Signature Algorithm: rsassaPss
     Hash Algorithm: sha256
     Mask Algorithm: mgf1 with sha256
```

I tried this:

```
public void encrypt(Collection<X509Certificate> certs)  {
    OutputEncryptor enc = new BcCMSContentEncryptorBuilder(CMSAlgorithm.AES192_CBC).build();
    SMIMEEnvelopedGenerator gen = new SMIMEEnvelopedGenerator();

    for (X509Certificate nCert : certs) {
         gen.addRecipientInfoGenerator(
         new JceKeyTransRecipientInfoGenerator(nCert, new AlgorithmIdentifier(PKCSObjectIdentifiers.id_RSAES_OAEP))
                .setProvider("BC"));
}
```

But it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work?" Do you get an error message? The wrong result? No result?

Comment: I don't have access to the log file right now, something about wrong algorithm.

Comment: We need much more specific information before we can start to help.

Comment: I totally understand, will provide log asap

Comment: Just a few corrections on terminology.  RSA-PSS is a signature algorithm, not an encryption algorithm.  RSA-OAEP is an encryption algorithm, so this is probably what you are looking for.  However we normally use RSA only for the purpose of encrypting a session key, for example an AES key, and then we use AES to encrypt the content (an email).

Comment: yes, that was my intention. But I need to encrypt this key with rsaes-oaep

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.bouncycastle.operator.jcajce.OperatorHelper.createAlgorithmParameters(Unknown Source)
 at org.bouncycastle.operator.jcajce.JceAsymmetricKeyWrapper.generateWrappedKey(Unknown Source)
 at org.bouncycastle.cms.KeyTransRecipientInfoGenerator.generate(Unknown Source)
 at org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSEnvelopedDataStreamGenerator.doOpen(Unknown Source)
 at org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSEnvelopedDataStreamGenerator.open(Unknown Source)` this is the stacktrace